# Prove $a^3+b^3+c^3\geq a^2b+b^2c+c^2a$

Tags: inequality

> if $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers,Prove:$$a^3+b^3+c^3\geq a^2b+b^2c+c^2a$$

*Things I have done so far:* I know the fact that $$a^3+b^3+c^3\geq\frac{1}{2}[ab(a+b)+bc(b+c)+ca(c+a)]$$

However i tried to reach the problem inequality,but I was not succesful.

Source of problem: school exam.

Comment: which school are you in?

Comment: @Aditya,it was not school main exam,it was a exam for students who study for mathematical olympiad.

Comment: Alternately, try Rearrangement inequality with $(a^2, b^2, c^2)$ and $(a, b, c)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By aM-GM:
$$\frac{2a^3+b^3}3\ge(a^6b^3)^{\frac13}=a^2b$$
$$\frac{2b^3+c^3}3\ge(b^6c^3)^{\frac13}=b^2c$$
$$\frac{2c^3+a^3}3\ge(c^6a^3)^{\frac13}=c^2a$$
Add them.